# Excel paste special values does not show value as displayed in the source cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to copy and paste row values from a sheet to another using the paste special values option. My source cell is a date custom formatted to YYYYMMDD

```
                       Source Cell
Orig Value = 1/15/2018     Formatted value (YYYYMMDD) = 20180115
```

What I want is to copy the formatted value of the source cell and paste in in the destination cell

```
                      Desired Results
Formatted Source cell = 20180115    Destination cell = 20180115
```

However, using the paste special - values results in a different amount in the destination cell

```
                      Actual Results
Formatted  Source cell = 20180115    Destination cell = 43115
```

Can the Excel guru's here guide me on how to make my desired results a reality.

P.S: The Excel i'm using is Excel 2013. Sorry for the terrible title
   : There should be no formatting done in the destination cell.

Answer (score 2):

Have you formatted the destination cell - otherwise excel will paste the date code which is 43115.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm sorry but I failed to mention that the destination cell could not contain any formatting so I really need to have the pasted value already appear in YYYYMMDD format instead of "43115" date code.

Answer (score 1):

*You need to do the following.*

1. Copy the Cell and move to the Destination.
2. Click Paste then hit Paste Special.
3. Select Value button and Ok.

*Check the Screen Shot.*

First I've copied the Original Date then in next Cell Paste it and applied the Format YYYYMMDD.

Then-after, first *Copied Original Date and Pasted it as Value* in 3 adjacent Cells, Formatted as  General, Number and Short Date.

Repeated the same sequence for 20180127.

[image]

**Note,** as alternative you can use the *DATEVALUE* formula also, but always remember it only considers Date in MM/DD/YYYY format.

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm sorry but I failed to mention that the destination cell could not contain any formatting so I really need to have the pasted value already appear in YYYYMMDD format instead of "43127" value.